# Jmeter Regular Expression Extractor not giving results

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded a workflow in Jmeter using Recording controller.
In that workflow, a URL parameter 'member_id' get generated and appear in URL.
This 'member_id' is getting used further in the workflow.

In the recorded script, value of 'member_id' is saved in a variable. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV4nL.png)

Here the problem is; When I execute the scripts, then instead of newly generated 'member_id', the saved value is getting used in the later samples.
I want to fetch the new value and update the saved value, so that it can be used in later samples

I have tried to fix this issue by fetching the 'member_id' from the URL and save it in a variable

I have tried 'Regular Expression Extractor' but I am not able to read the value.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz1Q1.png)

But when I print the response, I am getting only first digit of new 'member_id'.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j4yi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong regular expression, it stops whenever it finds the **first match**

According to the [JMeter documentation on Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#examples):

> `(` and `)` these enclose the portion of the match string to be returned
>
> `.` match any character
>
> `+` one or more times
>
> `?` don't be greedy, i.e. stop when **first match succeeds**

[image]

So the solution will be to remove the question mark from your regular expression:

```
member_id=(.+)
```

[image]

or even better, if you're looking for numbers you should limit your search criteria to digits only like:

```
member_id=(\d+)
```

References:

- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thanks for the help